# RSS News Feed with Images

Tags: php, rss, rss-reader

I have a PHP script to insert RSS news feeds into mysql database. I values which I am inserting now is `TITLE`, `DESCRIPTION`, `IMAGE`, `LINK`, `DATE`. My script insert all values successfully excluding images.

```
$feeds = array('https://news.google.com/news/section?topic=b&output=rss');
foreach( $feeds as $feed ) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
    foreach($xml->channel->item as $item)
    {
    $date_format = "j-n-Y"; // 7-7-2008
    echo date($date_format,strtotime($item->pubDate));  
    echo '<a href="'.$item->link.'" target="_blank">'.$item->title.'</a>';
    echo '<div>' . $item->description . '</div>';
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO rss_feeds (id, title, description, image, link, pubdate) 
    VALUES (
        '', 
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->title)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->description=htmlspecialchars(trim($item->description)))."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->image)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->link)."', 
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->pubDate)."')");       
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me where I am wrong

Comment: Echo out the query you're generating, and see if it runs when you run it yourself in the database.

Comment: @andrewsi I checked, its working

Comment: @andrewsi in description column I have all the data including images also. But I want to save image in seperate column "Image"

Comment: Is there anything in mysql_error()? I'd also suggest that you remove the `id` field from your INSERT, as you're not actually inserting anything into it. It might not cause the problem, but removing it can't hurt.

Comment: @andrewsi ya I remove that, by mistake i left it there :) so do u have any idea how to same image in seperate column or fetch just image from "Description" column

Comment: Assuming you just want the URL, I _think_ you can access it with `$item->image->url`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Shams, if you still looking for an answer, you then have to get deep in the HTML's description = parse the HTML.